# Why are my embedded fonts rendering improperly?

Tags: css, font-face, google-font-api

I am using the google fonts api, the font looks great on Google, but when I try to use it, it doesn't render properly. Here is an example:

https://twitter.com/dontdie/status/129234318299111424/photo/1

this is in Chrome, two different tabs. For some reason, Chrome is not using "subpixel rendering" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering ) on my site, but on google it is turned on.

Comment: I honestly cannot really see a difference, except the background colour google uses. This gives a slightly different tinge that might give the illusion that there is a difference. And I am a font geek. Am I missing something?

Comment: ..and a live web example might be better.

Comment: I did that example because it is hard to notice the difference when zoomed out. But, you'll notice the difference in the anti-aliasing. The top example uses subtle color differences to improve on the anti aliasing, whereas the bottom just uses shades of grey. Do you notice the difference in colors?

Comment: I see what you mean about the background, which would possibly account for the bluish hues in the anti-aliasing, but would not account for the orange colors. I'll try to add a subtle background and see if it produces the same results.

Comment: The rendering looks identical to me. The only difference is that one has a slight blue background that affects the edges. If it is this difficult to see it when when you blow it up, how can it be a problem in the right size.

Comment: The rendering looks sharper (in a bad way) in one than the other. When you zoom in as i have in the example, you can see the difference, which is in the anti-aliasing. This is a well-known technique, you can read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering, the question is why chrome is only doing it some of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out. adding these rules to my stylesheet seemed to fix it:

```
body, body * {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Just setting `subpixel-antialiased` didn't work, and just adding a background color to the body didn't work. This could probably be simplified to select just `*` or `html *`. Also, given that `subpixel-antialiased` is the default, removing that rule should work as well.